Why is Abstract Algebraic Logic not as useful for predicate logics?
I have read multiple times that the tools of Abstract Algebraic Logic are most useful only when restricted to propositional logics, meaning that they are much less useful in predicate logics.
Is that so? In what sense are the algebraic tools less useful? Could you give me some intuitive explanation as to why is that?
The remark about AAL's usefulness when restricted to prop. logics was always stated so generally that I do not know much more than what I wrote already, nonetheless let me write down some typical tools and goals of AAL.
Tools

constructing Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra
tools of universal algebra -- varieties/equational classes, quasi-varieties
Gentzen sequent calculus

Goals

giving algebraic semantics to different logics
classifying the logics
finding bridge theorems -- results that connect algebraic and logical properties
finding transfer theorems -- results that generalize properties from syntax to semantics


Do you have particular examples of the tools you are referring to?

@MarkKamsma it was always so generally stated that I actually do not know, I will think a bit about rephrasing the question and add some typical goals of AAL
